# Effectively filtering in a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've a dataframe having 3 columns - A, B and projects.
A and B contains the IDs given to a each student in a class and projects is #of projects they did together. The data is at the level of column A and column B

```
A |  B | projects
S2   S3    5
S2   S4    2
S5   S2    1
S5   S4    1
```

Note, a student can appear in any of the columns in input dataset (S2 is in both cola and colB)
Now, I need to find number of projects done by a student with all other students. The dataframe should look like this

```
id_ | StudentB | projects
S2     S3          5
S2     S5          1
S2     S4          2
S3     S2          5
S4     S2          2
S4     S5          1
S5     S4          1
```

Now, if I filter column id_ for a particular studentID, all related IDs should be listed in column StudentB

My solution ('all_student_id' is a distinct list of all IDs possible)-

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['id_', 'studentB','projects'])
for id_ in all_student_id:
    data_ = data[(data['A']== id_) | (data['B']== id_)] 

    a = data_[['A','projects']].rename(columns= {'A':'studentB'})
    b = data_[['B','projects']].rename(columns= {'B':'studentB'})

    a_b_concat = pd.concat([a,b], axis=0)
    formatted = a_b_concat[a_b_concat['studentB']!=id_]

    temp = pd.DataFrame({'id_':[id_]*formatted.shape[0]
                        })
    temp = pd.concat([temp, formatted.reset_index(drop = True)], axis = 1)

    final_df= pd.concat([final_df, temp])
```

While, I am able to do so using a for loop for all the distinct student ID, I believe that, it is not a scalable solution since the input dataset can be huge (30 million rows).

Any help in optimizing this solution will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
# sort the students - create a new data frame
df1 = df[['A','B']]
df1.values.sort(axis=1)
df1['projects'] = df['projects']

# now groupb
df1.groupby(['A','B'])['projects'].sum().reset_index()

    A   B   projects
0   S2  S3  5
1   S2  S4  2
2   S2  S5  1
3   S4  S5  1
```

Comment: The idea is that if I filter column A for S2, a list of all the students S2 has been a part of should be listed, which is not the case in the solution you posted ( S2 is in column B in row 2)

Comment: @user3788040 got it, making the change

Comment: @user3788040 check now

Comment: @YOLO your update didn't change the problem.  You need to do some sort of lookup/crosstab to get all combinations, right now you're only looking at the first column and second, not the other way around. All unique values should be represented in the first column according to the question.

Comment: @user3483203 to me the output only differs by adding duplicate rows of project value by interchanging the A, B values. For ex. S2-S3-5 , there is another row for S3-S2-5

Comment: Exactly, but that's what he's asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

So let me know if this sample works the way you want:

```
m=pd.DataFrame({'A':("S2","S2","S5","S5",'S2'),'B':("S3","S4","S2","S4",'S5'), 'projects':(5,2,1,1,6)})
```

This would be somewhat like:

```
    A   B  projects
0  S2  S3         5
1  S2  S4         2
2  S5  S2         1
3  S5  S4         1
4  S2  S5         6
```

Now what I assumed is, that you want, if ever let's say S2 and S5 came together, either in column 1 or column 2, they should counted as same as vice-versa. Taking this liberty, I performed some analysis and got this:

```
f=np.sort(m.iloc[:,0:2].values)
pd.concat((pd.DataFrame(f),m[['projects']]),axis=1).groupby([0,1])['projects'].sum()
```

Output I got was:

```
0   1 
S2  S3    5
    S4    2
    S5    7
S4  S5    1
```

It's renaming column as 0 and 1, which can be changed by set_axis. The main point is, is this how you want? That S2 and S5, no matter order, gave their sum as output?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are recommending `groupby`, but from your desired output I do not agree that is what you are looking for.  It seems that you simply want the relationships from `B->A` to also be included as relationships from `A->B`.  This is a trivial operation, which can be accomplished by stacking a reversed version of columns `A` and `B`

---

```
a = df.values
b = a[:, [1,0,2]].copy()

d = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((a, b)), columns=['id_', 'StudentB', 'projects'])
```

```
  id_ StudentB projects
0  S2       S3        5
1  S2       S4        2
2  S5       S2        1
3  S5       S4        1
4  S3       S2        5
5  S4       S2        2
6  S2       S5        1
7  S4       S5        1
```

Now you can lookup any student using only the `id_` column, although I would recommend a `pivot` here for a better data structure:

```
lookp = d.pivot('id_', 'StudentB', 'projects')
```

```
StudentB   S2   S3   S4   S5
id_
S2        NaN    5    2    1
S3          5  NaN  NaN  NaN
S4          2  NaN  NaN    1
S5          1  NaN    1  NaN
```

This gives you an easy way to lookup student relationships, with a `NaN` representing that two students *did not* work together on any projects.

```
>>> lookp.loc['S2', 'S3']
5
>>> lookp.loc['S3', 'S5']
nan
```